# Нужна линия вверху сайта как на Facebook или одноклассниках

Tags: html, css

Нужна линия как на соц. сетях Фэйсбук и Одноклассниках. Еще я видел в коде ее название *Top Line*, если вам это о чем то говорит. Помогите, пожалуйста, как сделать такую линию у себя на сайте?

Comment: Открываете исходные код этих сайтов и смотрите! Как же надоели вопросы "а как сделать так, как у ХХХ"...

Answer (score 1):

Найди сайт с рекламной строчкой Nolix (http://nolix.ru) или сам там "зарег-ся" и подсмотри код строчки!

Answer (score 0):

Я вот создал систему мгновенных сообщений недавно, так у неё есть топ-линия, посмотри:
**http://macfast.gixx.ru/**

Comment: так прикольно сайт прыгает когда по меню справа мышкой водишь :)

Comment: Ну это потому, что пиктограмма меню становится жирной.